# Is the article "a" or "an" necessary to describe a variable in the scientific paper?

Tags: indefinite-article

I am doing my paper in the field of information system economics. In the paper, I define a variable in the previous section, such as the intensity of competition γ. Whether "a higher γ" or "higher γ" is right? I'm not sure about the article "a".

Comment: It is impossible to tell without more context. You might also consider whether "a higher value of γ" or "higher value of γ" or "higher values of γ" would fit.

Comment: information system economics? Is that "the economics of information systems"? This is the deal: a is a general thing; the is a specific thing. A nice person is one who etc. The nice person sitting over there is X.

Comment: Thanks, adding the word "value" before the variable would make the sentence clear. Additionally, "the economics of IS" is better, but sometimes we just call it "IS".